# 静かにさせてくれ to mean something like "let me have peace"

Tags: meaning, usage

This question is about the usage of 静かにさせてくれ. At first I would have thought this to be used to ask someone to have someone else be quiet e.g. someone asking a parent to have their kid be quiet. But I also saw it in a different context where it seemed to imply something along the lines of "let me have peace and quiet". I say this because if they were just asking the person to be silent they would have said 静かにしてください which is different.

If my understanding of this usage is correct, can anyone explain I guess how this works grammatically as I'm not sure what を would be attached to if the sentence was said without dropping.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

静かにさせてくれ literally means "(Please do me a favor and) let me be quiet", so "Let me have piece" is the closer translation. The implied を-marked agent of させる is 私 ("me"), although 私を/俺を/etc is almost always dropped in a sentence like this.

～させてくれ/～させてください is a common pattern.

- 行かせてくれ Allow me to go.
- 俺を笑わせてくれ Make me laugh.

Comment: I'm still confused by this one. Isn't the literal translation "please allow me to make it quiet"? This sounds like I am the one responsible for stopping the noise, but I'm assuming the meaning is supposed to be for the other party to stop being noisy.